# Gradle: how to keep kotlin and java in the same source folder?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I would like to have kotlin and java files in the same folder like:

```
src/main/xxx/JavaClass.java
src/main/xxx/KotlinClass.kt

src/test/xxx/JavaTestClass.java
src/test/xxx/KotlinTestClass.kt
```

i don't care if `xxx` is `kotlin`, `java`, `whatever`. i just want to have all the files providing a single functionality in one place with working cross-references / cross-compilation.

how can i configure it in gradle?

Comment: We just have everything in `src/main/java/...` and it works O_o?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you! i had it in `kotlin` folder and it didn't. i had no reason to try 'java' folder :) i'm still surprised by some conventions

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the wrong operator; `+=` can be used to extend the class-path.

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
}
```

referencing a separate module is still more solid than within the same module:

a) because some Gradle DSL is Java or Kotlin specific.

b) the test-runners do not care about other technologies.

adding more complexity (a library module) barely solves a problem; but in this case, it circumvents it - because it permits another one `build.gradle` & test-runner. which otherwise would not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/xxx']
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src/main/xxx']
    test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/xxx']
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src/test/xxx']
}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific.